Entra Id (Azure) Adding Is Device Managed To SAML Token
We have our Workday tenant setup with SSO through SAML in Entra Id.  Workday has a SAML Identity Provider managed device attribute that we would like to use.
Is there a process for adding a restricted claim (http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/devicecontext/claims/ismanaged) to the SAML token in Entra Id?  If not, is there a different way I can accomplish getting that value mapped or transformed in the SAML token to pass to Workday?
When I try to add the claim in Entra, it isn't listed, and I assume that is because it's in the restricted set.


Check this let me know if it works for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/412018/azure-ad-saml-intune-ismanaged-attribute

I tried that during my initial research.  I am able to add the section to the manifest, but then when I go look at the token configuration, "the claim is not supported and will not be returned in the token".
